# Axes of GraphicalView of AchartEngine

Tags: achartengine

I have a graphicalview element which updates in realtime.
I know from the beginning the interval in which my values will stay.
Therefore I would like my Y axes to be set in a way that shows that entire interval from the beginning.
At the momente the Y axes changes on the basis of the values that arrives. For example if my values' interval  is (0, 10) but I have received only points whos Y is equal to 3, the maximum values of the Y axes will be 3, instead I want it to be 10.

Any suggestion?
I know that I have to set some parameters of the XYMultipleSeriesRender but which one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do what you need:

```
// TODO: provide your own values here
renderer.setYAxisMin(0);
renderer.setYAxisMax(10);
```